tikzDevice not generating entire standalone file
I am trying to save a geographical map generated with ggplot2 using the library(tikzDevice) in R to a standalone document.
The .tex file generated only runs to up to line 101766 and the \end{document} is never written to the file.
setTikzDefaults()
  options(tikzDefaultEngine = 'xetex') # for degree unicode symbol
  options(tikzXelatexPackages = c(
    getOption( "tikzXelatexPackages" ),
    "\\usepackage{siunitx}\n"
  ))
  tikz(file="../../report/gfx/gg_map.tex",
       width=9,
       height=9,
       standAlone=TRUE)
  gg_map
  dev.off(dev.list()["RStudioGD"])

Subsequent compilation then fails probably at the aforementioned line, as the log shows:
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/lmss/b/n on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/b/n on input line 15.

(d:/Programs/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translations/translations-basic-
dictionary-english.trsl
File: translations-basic-dictionary-english.trsl (english translation file `tra
nslations-basic-dictionary')
)
Package translations Info: loading dictionary `translations-basic-dictionary' f
or `english'. on input line 15.
)
*
! Emergency stop.
<*> 
    
End of file on the terminal!

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 21722 strings out of 474705
 509448 string characters out of 5755828
 4943482 words of memory out of 5000000
 43697 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 558109 words of font info for 41 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 102i,5n,107p,501b,644s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
No pages of output.

In view of the almost reached memory limit 4943482 words of memory out of 5000000 during compilation, could the tikzDevice package fail silently due similar a memory limitation?
I tried to increase this limit by adding main_memory=70000000 to texlive/2024/texmf.cfg under Windows, however the change has not effect on the log upon recompilation. How and where to increase this limit correctly?
I would be thankful for any insight into the problem or suggestion for a solution.

the * prompt is not an error it simply means tex reached the end of the file and is waiting for more input, but you are running tex in batch mode so no input possible, so it stops. As such it is not really a tex question, it is a R question about why it wrote an incomplete file (in which case I don't think you have provided enough information, or that it's on topic as you probably need to ask on an R forum)

Thank you, David Carlisle, for your answer and insight! I posted on the tikzDevice issue tracker on github, but shortly after found the solution to my two problems, see below.

I solved the problem of incomplete output by using dev.off() after gg_map instead of dev.off(dev.list()["RStudioGD"]) to print to the .tex file.
The memory error persisted so I increased main_memory = 7000000 in texmf.cnf (which can be found with kpsewhich texmf.cnf) and then ran fmtutil-sys --all. After that compilation of the pdf terminated successfully.

Nice. Thanks for sharing. // As David mentioned your problem and solution may be interesting for the R community, too.
